# How to remove unused Symbols?

Tags: sketch-app, symbols

I am wondering how to deal with the new Symbols in Sketch: If I don't need a symbol anymore, (deleting all instances or detaching) it seems to stay in the symbols palette anyway (for what reason?) So my Symbols collection just grows endlessly — Is there any way or plugin to tell sketch that if a symbol itself is not longer used in any instance in the document, that it should be removed from the symbols collection?

Answer (score 2):

Just came across that exact plugin to "tell sketch that if a symbol itself is not longer used in any instance in the document, that it should be removed from the symbols collection".  http://sketchhunt.com/2016/05/28/remove-unused-symbols-official-plugin-sketch/
It appears to be created by a developer on the Bohemian team, and can also be found on Github https://github.com/sketchplugins/remove-unused-symbols
or by searching Sketch Toolbox for "Remove unused symbols"

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!